# Hibernate 6.4 - datasource vs provider_class check is reversed in ConnectionProviderInitiator.java

Tags: hibernate, jpa, connection, persistence, datasource

It looks like that starting hibernate 6.3, the class ConnectionProviderInitiator has reversed the order in which it checks for "hibernate.connection.datasource" and "hibernate.connection.provider_class". However the documentation says otherwise and doesn't match with the code, below are the links.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-connectionprovider-datasource

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.4.2/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/connections/internal/ConnectionProviderInitiator.java

This is causing an issue with our application as we depend on the provider_class to be checked first since we have a custom DatasourceConnectionProvider class that overrides the default"getConnection()" method. We are not able to upgrade from Wildfly 29 to 31 due this issue. Looking for any ideas/suggestions on how we can handle this issue.

Thanks!